# Hyperlinking an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm not sure if this is even possible.

I've got the following code;

`<a href="javascript:foo();"><iframe src="http://www.domain.com/content.html" width="200" height="50"></iframe></a>`

Now, I would have assumed that would've hyper-linked the entire iFrame area, however it only hyperlinks the border.

Is it possible to hyperlink the entire iframe area?

Comment: It's a placeholder for a function to be called, you didn't get that?

Comment: Apologies, I did not get that. `function` is a reserved word so what you've got there is syntactically invalid JS. [Metasyntactic variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variables) help avoid this sort of confusion.

Comment: what you want to do? Please make it clear. You want to work "foo" function once click on iframe border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, that's not valid.  you can't even reliably get a click event off of the element containing the iframe.

e.g.,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">         
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#bob').click(function(e){
                    alert('hi');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bob" style="padding:100px;background:red;"><iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

notice that if you click the iframe, no alert fires - but if you click anywhere else (in red), it will.  if this were otherwise, there'd be abuse...

Comment: Is it formally invalid?  If so, why?  I'm finding it difficult to actually see where in the spec that is disallowed.

Comment: if you're talking about markup, AFAIK, anchors should only have phrase content - although i think HTML5 will allow block-level content.  as far as the javascript, I don't think there's a real "spec" for dom behavior like this, and it's vendor-specific, but (again, AFAIK), it's not going to work, nor should it IMO

Comment: Yeah he's right, it's invalid. The only possible way that it might work, is to position a div absolutely above the iframe, and set opacity to 0 (which is only valid in certain browsers), and I'm not even sure that would work.

Answer (score 0):

What actually do you mean by "hyperlink the iframe"?

You could try to use an `onclick` event for the `iframe`, or position a `div` with an `onclick` and transparent background above the `iframe`. Another possibility is to set the `a` to `display: block` and position it above the `iframe`.